# Keywords inside a spaceless string (using NLP?)

Tags: algorithm, nlp, keyword

I am trying to find the relevant set of keywords inside a spaceless string. An example would be:

```
freelancemarketingconsultant
```

By reading it, you can distinguish the following keywords:

```
freelance marketing consultant
```

You can see the task is not trivial, as a common confusion would be to distinguish between "free" and "lance".

Are there known (potentially NLP) techniques to extract keywords from such strings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Viterbi algorithm to find the most likely (best) way to split the string. There's a library called [wordsegment](http://www.grantjenks.com/docs/wordsegment/) that does this in Python, and you can read more about the technique at [Peter Norvig's page](http://norvig.com/ngrams/).

There's also a recent research project called [Hashtag Master](http://sdl898-ritter2.cse.ohio-state.edu:8153/) which uses neural methods to tokenize hashtags.

This isn't a common problem in English, but it's standard in languages were spaces don't split words, like Japanese. There are a variety of methods, and research continues, but Viterbi based methods generally have the best balance of speed and accuracy.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the documentation! Perfectly answers my question!! Regards